# npm ERR! Object.entries is not a function while using pdfmake

Tags: npm, npm-install

I installed pdfmake and got an error like:

> npm ERR! Object.entries is not a function.

My node version is v6.6.0. After installing any other package I'm also
getting the same error.

Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: The portion of the error message you've included is too short to provide an answer. Please [edit] the question to include more of the error message, and any code that is referenced by the error.

Answer (score 0):

Update node to version 8.x+ to resolve this issue which has build in support for this.